# id passing alternative for website

Tags: javascript, php, database

I just want to ask if there is a better way for me to pass IDs for the DB on the website.

Right now I pass it by changing the 'button' attribute 'ID' into the ID of the element I want to edit. so when I pass it to the controller, I pass along the values I want to upload and the button's ID for update. I know it's unsafe, but is there an alternative?

If it's better, can you at least point me at the right direction on good web design?

If it helps, I use Codeigniter.

Comment: Thought of using a `data-` attribute?

Comment: Use either a query param in your form's action attribute, eg `<form action="whatever?id=123">` or set an hidden input, `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relax.  There is nothing inherently insecure about passing the ID to the browser and POSTing it or putting it on the query string.  The ID is not itself sensitive.

Just like Phil said above, a

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" />
```

is a common way to pass the ID around.

The element of safety comes in the handling of the next request.  ALWAYS check that the user making the request is authorized to modify the data that correspond to the ID.  This is generally done by checking the user's login cookie.  There are other methods of authentication but the bottom line is to prove that the user you have should be editing the data they are trying to edit.

Comment: +1 to always checking authorization on form submission. While it's good enough to submit an ID like this, remember that its trivial for the user to tamper with it and change it.